# DotNet Core EF converts UTC time from database to local system time

Tags: mysql, .net-core, timezone

I am writing an application in dotnet core 6.0 using a MySQl database accessed via Polmelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql. When I store a UTC date into my database, it stores correctly as UTC time. But when I read the value back, it's converted back to local system time... which is unfortunate as the app is running in multiple timezones. And when I try to convert to local time, it, in effect, does the conversion twice.

```
var referral = await Task.Run(() => context.Referrals.Where(i => i.ReferralId == id).FirstOrDefault());
```

referral.CreationTime returns a local time when the stored time in mysql is UTC. WTF -- losing my mind.

Comment: If I manually pull the two time fields out and overwrite what is in the object, I can pull out the UTC code: {referral.ReferralCreatedDateTime = await Task.Run(() => context.Referrals.Where(i => i.ReferralId == id).Select(c => c.ReferralCreatedDateTime).FirstOrDefault()); }}   Is it me or is this insane?

Comment: The behavior you described makes me think you are saving your data into a `TIMESTAMP` field, but you expect it to behave like a `DATETIME` field.  See [the MySQL docs for the differences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).  That said, you didn't ask your question in any way that we can see what data types you are using on either the .NET side or the MySQL side.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Thanks.